# Error when running an app using trigger.io (v2.2.10) on a USB connected device (iPad iOS 8.1) - Unable to mount developer disk image. (e8000033)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, trigger.io

Running an app using trigger.io (v2.2.10) on a USB connected device (iPad iOS 8.1) from an OS X(10.10.2) machine (w/ Xcode 6.2) is failing during the debug phase, below is the error section

```
[100%] Installed package /Users/aaa/forge-workspace/bbb/development/ios/device-ios.app
[INFO] ------ Debug phase ------
[INFO] Starting debug of Unknown Device 'iPad' (---) connected through USB...
[INFO] [  0%] Looking up developer disk image
[INFO] [ !! ] Unable to mount developer disk image. (e8000033)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had some issues with newer iOS devices not being detected that were addressed in platform version 2.2.11

https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/release_notes.html